# Problem in displaying data from SAP HANA to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, hana, business-objects, sap-web-ide

After connecting SAP HANA to Power BI, every time I want to display the data in a chart or a tab I get this error message :

error old DB or odbc [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32] general error : 258 insufficient privileges

Note that the system user has all the privileges

Comment: What priviledge do you have for the connection with the HANA database? Review the connection.

Comment: the connection is made through the SYSTEM user that have all the privileges

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify your use case?  If you are `SYSTEM`, I assume you are using something like HANA Express Edition.  Are you using Power BI to select against a Calculation View?  If so, you'll need at the very least `SELECT` on the `_SYS_BIC` schema (which is also a grossly large GRANT to do, however who cares if this is a sandbox.)

You may also need to grant `SYSTEM` some Analytic Privileges if it is a calculation view and you did not blank out that option.

Again, this is somewhat speculative unless you can be more specific what type of catalog object you are selecting against in HANA.

Answer (score 0):

The HANA `SYSTEM` user is the root database **administration** user. It does not and should not have access to the application data at all.

To use reporting tools with your application data you need to create a DB user and assign this user the read privileges for the DB objects you want to access.
Using `SYSTEM` for this (or really for anything else than bootstrapping the system) is **not** recommend and leaves a gaping security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the mentioned security issue with SYSTEM user for just reporting I agree that you should check and assign the analytic privileges on reporting objects to reporting user. Because they must be granted explicitly: there's no "view all" SQL analytic privilege in HANA, so no superuser that can view everything via any Calculation view.

To figure out the problem object you should set trace level to debug for your reporting user and indexserver.authorization component.